# Probability of cycles of length at most $g$ in a random graph

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

I am working on a homework problem. The essence of it is as follows:

Fix some integer $g$, a probability $p\in [0,1]$, and a linear function $f(n)$, where $n$ is the number of vertices of a random graph. If the probability of having a particular edge in a graph is $p$, what is the probability that the number of cycles of length at most $g$ in a random graph with $n$ vertices will surpass $f(n)$?

I'd like just some hints in the direction of the solution. The actual question has $p$ as a function of $n$ and $g$, and asks for the result in the limit as $n\to\infty$, but I would like to understand the question in general.

Comment: I'll delete my answer so you're more likely to get the combinatorial argument you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you'll find a closed form for the finite case; the calculation is complicated because of the correlations between different cycles; I think the problem was posed for the infinite case for a reason :-)

For the infinite case, you can calculate the expected number of cycles, whose behaviour for $n\to\infty$ will depend on how $p$ depends on $n$. You can also calculate the variance of the number of cycles as the expected value of the square minus the square of the expected value. Then you can use [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) to show that the probability for the number to deviate appreciably from the expected number goes to $0$ for $n\to\infty$, so you can just compare $f(n)$ with the expected number.